# Class and scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, scope

I wrote the following code in Javascript.

```
function main()
{
    this.a ;
    this.set = function()
    {
        a = 1;
    }
}

var l = new main();

alert("Initial value of a is "+ l.a );
l.set();
alert("after calling set() value of a is   "+ l.a );
```

In both cases i got value of a as undefined .Why a is undefined even after I called set()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to javascript this:

```
function main()
{
    this.a ;
    this.set = function()
    {
        a = 1;
    }
}
```

will looks like

```
function main();

{ // starts unattached object literal
    this.a ;
    this.set = function();

    { // starts another unattached object literal 
        a = 1; // sets value to   window.a
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to refer to `a` with `this.a`.

Otherwise, you are referring to a local variable `a` (had you used `var`, omitting it has made an `a` property on the `window` object, essentially a global) and not the object's property `a` (`this` will be bound to the newly created object).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Fh5mZ/).

Comment: Right; when you say `a = 1;` you are declaring a global variable named `a`.

Comment: @JustinEthier: Cheers, I made that more explicit :)

Comment: Thank you all .I am just a beginner in Javascript classes.I now understood the scope of variables

Answer (score 2):

Your "set" function is missing a reference to `this`:

```
   this.a = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers: there are no classes in Javascript, only objects. You can construct class-like things, but the javascript inheritance model is [prototypal](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html). In your code, `main` is a [constructor function](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs2.shtml), from which you can derive instances.

Many people are still trying to force javascript into all kinds of classic OOP patterns. It's all perfectly possible, but it's crippling the language. Take some time to watch [this series of lectures](http://yuiblog.com/crockford/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a property of an object undefined as you've done it. And you referenced the property `a` incorrectly in the `case` method. Here is the correction:

```
function main() {
    this.a = null;
    this.set = function() {
        this.a = 1;
    }
}

var l = new main();

alert("Initial value of a is " + l.a);
l.set();
alert("after calling set() value of a is   " + l.a);
```